# Android Map has loaded fully

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have a requirement where in i need to take an image of mapview and use it for displaying in a pdf. I am able to take the image and display it in pdf but the only issue is when i am taking the snap of the MapView sometimes the map is not fully loded.

Is there any event which can notify me if the map is fully loaded or any other way to know if the map is loaded in android app.

Answer (score 0):

So after too many days of findings what i end up with is that there is no 100 % guranteed way of finding it. There are few methods present thought one of them being:

```
canCoverCenter
public boolean canCoverCenter()
Checks whether we currently have a map tile to cover the center of the map. 

Returns:
True if there is a tile for the center, false otherwise.
```

---

But it only notifies for the center tile and not all the tiles. :(